# How can I use requestAnimationFrame along with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

See the following snippet of code.

It creates a loader on click of a button. But the animation is not smooth.

I have recently read about `requestAnimationFrame` function which can do this job. But how can I use it to replace `setInterval` altogether since there is no way to specify time in `requestAnimationFrame` function.

Can it be used in conjunction with `setInterval` ?

```js
let idx = 1;
const timetoEnd = 5000;

function ProgressBar(width){
  this.width = width || 0;
  this.id = `pBar-${idx++}`;
  this.create = () => {
    let pBar = document.createElement('div');
    pBar.id = this.id;
    pBar.className = `p-bar`;
    pBar.innerHTML = `<div class="loader"></div>`;
    return pBar;
  };
  this.animator = () => {
      let element = document.querySelector(`#${(this.id)} div`);
      if(this.width < 100){
        this.width++;
        element.style.width = `${this.width}%`;
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
  };
  this.animate = () => {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.animator, timetoEnd/100);
  }
}

function addLoader (){
  let bar1 = new ProgressBar(40);
  let container = document.querySelector("#container");
  container.appendChild(bar1.create());
  bar1.animate();
}
```

```css
.p-bar{
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.p-bar .loader{
  width: 0;
  background: #1565C0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add loader" onclick="addLoader()" />
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame): _"...The callback method is passed a single argument, a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, which indicates the current time when callbacks queued by requestAnimationFrame() begin to fire."_ Check the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Notes) on how to work with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `requestAnimationFrame` is the recommended way to avoid UI jam when doing animation.

You can remember the absolute starting time at start instead of trying to do this at each frame. Then it's just a matter of computing a width based on the delta time between start and current time.

Also, `document.querySelector` is considered a relatively "heavy" operation so I added `this.element` to avoid doing it at each frame.

Here is how to new width is computed: `((100 - this.startWidth) / timetoEnd) * deltaT + this.startWidth`

1. `100 - this.startWidth` is the total amount of width we have to animate
2. `(100 - this.startWidth) / timetoEnd` is how much width each second must add to (1)
3. `((100 - this.startWidth) / timetoEnd) * deltaT` is how much width we have to add to (1)
4. We just have to shift the whole thing `this.startWidth` px to have the frame's width

Also notice that some of this computation is constant and do not have to be computed on each frame, which I left as an exercise :)

Here is your slightly adapted code:

```js
let idx = 1;
const timetoEnd = 5000;

function ProgressBar(startWidth){
  this.startWidth = startWidth || 0;
  this.id = `pBar-${idx++}`;
  this.create = () => {
    let pBar = document.createElement('div');
    pBar.id = this.id;
    pBar.className = `p-bar`;
    pBar.innerHTML = `<div class="loader"></div>`;
    return pBar;
  };
  this.animator = () => {
      const deltaT = Math.min(new Date().getTime() - this.start, timetoEnd);
      if(deltaT < timetoEnd){
        const width = ((100 - this.startWidth) / timetoEnd) * deltaT + this.startWidth;
        this.element.style.width = `${width}%`;
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animator.bind(this))
      }
  };
  this.animate = () => {
    this.element = document.querySelector(`#${(this.id)} div`);
    this.start = new Date().getTime();
    this.animator();
  }
}

function addLoader (){
  let bar1 = new ProgressBar(40);
  let container = document.querySelector("#container");
  container.appendChild(bar1.create());
  bar1.animate();
}
```

```css
.p-bar{
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.p-bar .loader{
  width: 0;
  background: #1565C0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add loader" onclick="addLoader()" />
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution looks good. Just one question though, Do we not clear the requestAnimationFrame ?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` only requests one frame, it behave like `setTimeout` for that matter. This is why I call `requestAnimationFrame` in this.animator

Comment: That's right. I got it. 
I have observed one thing though, the calculation above for width does not make the inner width 100%. If you inspect the DOM, each loader finishes at different widths.

Comment: oups :) my bad, i edited the solution to max `deltaT` to `timetoEnd`. Since we don't know when the execution happens, deltaT could be more than 5000

Comment: Thanks mate. However it was not making the width 100%, so I added a small else if block at the end to accomplish that. :)  Accepted your answer. Hope to get reciprocated.